# iOS Crash log: what is 'purgeable_ptr_in_use_enumerator'?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

is anyone familiar with the crash message purgeable_ptr_in_use_enumerator from libsystem_c.dylib?

My hunch is that it has to do with some mutable object being mutated at the same time its accessed in another point in code but just wanted to see if anyone has a good understanding of this error message.

For what its worth, here is the preceding error log

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib __pthread_kill + 8

1    libsystem_c.dylib  abort + 94

2    libsystem_c.dylib  purgeable_ptr_in_use_enumerator

3    libsystem_c.dylib  free_tiny_botch + 84

4    libsystem_c.dylib  free + 170

5    CoreFoundation __rehashs + 162

6    CoreFoundation -[__NSSetM addObject:] + 214

7    CoreFoundation -[NSMutableSet addObjectsFromArray:] + 382
```

Comment: It's not quite a crash message, rather an internal function of CoreFoundation. Hint: you're most likely missing understanding of memory management.

Comment: oh interesting. I wonder what could be causing this crash then? perhaps that array has been released some point earlier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an error message. It's a static function defined in `magazine_malloc.c` in libsystem_c. See [this](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-583/gen/magazine_malloc.c) if you're interested in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Check the free disk space on your device. One of our users kept crashing in random places and all his logs had this in common. Turns out that he had only 2-3 MB of free space on his device.